# Create a public connection to SQL Server in Excel with Microsoft Query

Tags: sql-server, excel, connection-string, microsoft-query

I want to import data from SQL Server to Excel. Because I want to use parameters in the query's, I use a Microsoft Query instead of the standard SQL Server connection.

When making a custom connection the following screen comes up:

[image]

My problem is that the connection string this creates contains my name. Is it possible to create a public connection string that everyone can use? Or can that be done with this connection string aswell?

Below the connection string:

```
DRIVER=SQL Server Native Client 11.0;SERVER=[SERVERNAME];UID=[MY LOGIN];Trusted_Connection=Yes;APP=Microsoft Office 2010;WSID=[PC NAME];DATABASE=[DATABASE NAME];
```

Comment: *Don't* use Microsoft Query. It's deprecated. It's been replaced by PowerQuery which is included in Excel since 2013 (I think) and is available as a separate free download for 2010.

Comment: BTW whatever `the standard SQL Server connection` means, you *can* use queries or stored procedures with parameters

Comment: Finally `;UID=[MY LOGIN];` is ignored when you use `Trusted_Connection=Yes;`. This means that Windows Authentication is used and Excel connects using the real user's account

Comment: You'll find an intro to Power Query [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/introduction-to-microsoft-power-query-for-excel-6e92e2f4-2079-4e1f-bad5-89f6269cd605)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks, I was looking for the answer if the UID would be ignored.I can't use power query because of software restrictions

Comment: The only possible restriction would be using Excel 2007, or 2010 without the ability to install Addins. *Newer* versions come with Power Query as the data loading mechanism.

Comment: Perhaps you should use a library like EPPlus to generate an Excel file in code without using Excel?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Excel 2010 is installed without permission for add-ins